# Is it normal that Ready To Run publishing takes 10 times longer?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

EDIT: In the meanwhile, I opened [an issue in the MSBuild GitHub project](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/6046) as this topic haven't received any replies for 10 days.

EDIT 2: **See my own answer below.**

I'm experimenting with building an ASP.NET Core 3.1-targeted application with [R2R publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#readytorun-images) enabled to accelerate the execution of automated UI tests.
The solution has around 30 projects (+10 test projects) with 181k LOC, out of that 54k is executable according to VS code metrics.

My machine has 4 cores / 8 threads and I took the following measurements:

1. Publish without R2R takes 2 minutes on average:

```
dotnet publish Solution.sln --configuration Release --output "publish" --runtime win-x64
```

2. With R2R it falls between 25 and 35 minutes:

```
dotnet publish Solution.sln --configuration Release --output "publish" --runtime win-x64 -p:PublishReadyToRun=true
```

In the first few iterations of my testing Windows Defender was interfering (continuously spinning up for a second or two) noticeably, but I put crossgen.exe on ignore for now.
Looking at the Task Manager, I also noticed that crossgen.exe does not spawn more than 4 instances at the same time (could it be a hard limit on physical cores?), but I haven't seen more than 3 of them working at the same time. Also, crossgen processes' CPU usage was mostly few second bursts to 15-20% (compared to total) CPU usage. So the "uptime" and intensity is way below what MSBuild produces during a normal build process.

My .NET info:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.101
 Commit:    d05174dc5a

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.1
  Commit:  b02e13abab

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

So my question is: **Am I missing something or doing wrong in terms of tooling / configuration?** The 10x increase in build time seems quite extreme...

Comment: I experienced similar differences too. What's strange that the R2R publish doesn't utilize the CPU as well as the standard one by far, my old 4-core running around 60-70% utilization with a lot of other stuff running (>90% usually in standard publish but with great variance). It seems it basically goes through each project in the solution one by one, not in a parallelized nature.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the "-graph" switch ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2019#graph-option)) solves the issue (which can be passed on to dotnet.exe too) bringing the publish time to a reasonable level (few minutes). Without it, each project in the solution will be built independently, so dependencies will be rebuilt each time they occur.

Also, check out [this GitHub issue in the .NET Runtime repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/47272) for (hopefully) further information from the .NET team.

Comment: Thank you so much, this gave our build a 30+% performance boost :)

Comment: P.S.: For our .NET 6 solution, I did remove the graph parameter from our build (I used -p:graph=true in dotnet publish command) and the performance stayed the same - so I think the main performance boost came from building the solution file instead of building the projects. For excluding the test and library projects, I did use the <IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable> configuration in our .csproj files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! We have abandoned using/experimenting with R2R a while ago, but a lot happened in the SDK (and our code) since then, so might worth revisiting it.